# TypeError: soap.createClientAsync is not a function

Tags: node.js, soap

I am getting this error while working with `soap` npm package.
App is built in Meteor.

Below is the code:

```
soap.createClientAsync(url).then((client) => {
    return client.someMethod(soapArgs, function(err, result) {
        if (result) {
            console.log('result');
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
 }).then((result) => {
     console.log('soap.createClientAsync');
     console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: How have you installed the soap package and how are you requiring it? It should be installed "locally" using `npm install soap` inside your project dir, and required using `require('soap')`

Comment: @Vasan, yeah I have installed it locally and imported using `require('soap')`.

Comment: can you debug what soap is ?

Comment: yeah, I am able to see print soap and all its properties are visible but not `createClientAsync`

Comment: Although now I was able to use `soap.createClient` and I don't require `soap.createClientAsync` but still if someone is able to track the issue, it might be helpful in future.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using TypeScript? You must import with `import * as soap from "soap"` because in soap lib doesn't have a default export.